# create and add query result column to an existing table SQL BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table 'zzz' with GpsLatitude and GpsLongitude columns. I want to create a single GPS column (PointWKT) from GpsLatitude and GpsLongitude columns and add it to the existing table 'zzz'.

Query for creating a single column PointWKT:

```
SELECT
  ST_GeogPoint(GpsLongitude, GpsLatitude)  AS PointWKT,
FROM
  `xxx.yyy.zzz`
```

**I would like to add this query result column PointWKT to an existing table 'zzz'. Correct answer:**

```
SELECT DateTime, SerialNumber, TotalWorkingHours, ...
  ST_GeogPoint(GpsLongitude, GpsLatitude)  AS PointWKT,
FROM
  `login-eko.telematics_latest_K2020.tractor_reports_p` BoundaryWKT
```

Comment: I have posted your answer as [Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

Answer (score 0):

This answer was provided by @Kuki.

> You just use `ST_GeogPoint(GpsLongitude, GpsLatitude)  AS PointWKT`
>   within you select statement, as follows:

```
SELECT DateTime, SerialNumber, TotalWorkingHours, ...
  ST_GeogPoint(GpsLongitude, GpsLatitude)  AS PointWKT,
FROM
  `project.dataset.table` BoundaryWKT
```